# Converting these chmod commands to cacls?

Tags: permissions, chmod, cacls

Perhaps someone could help me. I'd like to convert the following chmod commands to use on Windows 7 but my understanding is lacking.

```
/bin/chmod -R u+w,go-w,a+r somedirectory
/bin/chmod a+x anotherdirectory
```

Thank you greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of examples taken from the [cacls manual/help page](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html).

Grant full control to User "Dean" to all files and subdirectories:

```
cacls somedirectory /e /t /p Dean:f
```

Add Read-Only permission to a single file

```
CACLS myfile.txt /E /G "Power Users":R
```

Add Full Control permission to a second group of users

```
CACLS myfile.txt /E /G "FinanceUsers":F
```

Now revoke the Read permissions from the first group

```
CACLS myfile.txt /E /R "Power Users"
```

Now give the first group Full-control:

```
CACLS myfile.txt /E /G "Power Users":F
```

Give the Finance group Full Control of a folder and all sub folders

```
CACLS c:\docs\work /E /T /C /G "FinanceUsers":F
```

It looks like the "/t" does the recursion into all files and subdirectories, and "/e" edits instead of replaces the access control list (permissions).  You can use multiple options per command but I have been having trouble changing everything at once.  Cacls looks like it wants specific groups and users as opposed to the o,g,a options.

Here's some more info from "cacls /?":

```
 /G user:perm  Grant specified user access rights.

              Perm can be: R  Read

                           W  Write

                           C  Change (write)

                           F  Full control

/R user       Revoke specified user's access rights (only valid with /E).

/P user:perm  Replace specified user's access rights.

              Perm can be: N  None

                           R  Read

                           W  Write

                           C  Change (write)

                           F  Full control
```